# How to make a JS for loop async

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I have to loop over some data and make an HTTP call to return data based on the content and after I have all the HTTP data back I need to continue and process the data.

Right now I have this.

```js
let test;
myVar.forEach(async (x) => {
   await this.getMyDataFromService(x).subscribe(resp => {
       test.push(resp);
   }
});

//Process data
console.log(test);
```

when I console.log the resp is always empty and there is no data.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: maybe define test as an array first?
and console.log on test, not on resp as that is valid only inside the subscribe function.

Comment: Have a look at this to await all the async calls: https://dev.to/jamesliudotcc/how-to-use-async-await-with-map-and-promise-all-1gb5

Comment: Your code should look like this, by using the mentioned methods. 
`async function yourMainFunction() {
  await Promise.all(
    myVar.map((x, i) => {
      this.getMyDataFromService(x).subscribe(resp => {
        test.push(resp);
      })
    })
  );
}`
Also, the value of _resp_ is empty, because that variable is available only within the scope of subscribe's callback function. You can see the value of created _test_ array.

Comment: Sorry at the end didn’t mean REsp meant test.